# How do you find the current platform in robotframework?

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to find a Keyword or automatic variable that contains the current platform that the robot framework suite is being run on.

I assume it must know to allow it to access the file system.

I wanted to use this to load variable resources depending on the current platform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Evaluate](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html?r=2.8.4#Evaluate) keyword to get the platform from python using [sys.platform](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.platform):

```
*** Test Cases ***
| Example which logs the current platform
| | ${platform}= | Evaluate | sys.platform | sys
| | log | ${platform}
```

The exact values that are returned are documented in the [sys.platform](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.platform) documentation.

For more fine-grained information, such as processor type, you can use the [platform](https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html) module in a similar manner.